# Google Apps - Data Transfer API - transfert only some ressources

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to use the new [Data Transfer API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/) for Google Apps Domain and I would like to transfer some specific Google Drive files from one user to another. It seems we can use this API to transfer a "full service" (eg: all files from Google Drive) and not only some specific files.

Is my understanding of this API is correct or is it possible to limit the transfer to specific resources?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use Data transfer API for transferring all application data. But if you want to transfer specific files then you can use Drive API. check this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. The API enables you to transfer ownership of application data (currently Drive documents and Google+ pages) in bulk. It essentially allows you to automate the manual ownership transfer task documented [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1247799). You might want to read this [blog](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com.au/2015/09/programmatically-transfer-ownership-of.html) here which has some useful background information.

The only way to achieve what you want is to use the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) (not to be confused with the [Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/)).